# Xamarin.Forms - Resource.Designer is missing important fields/constants

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm experiencing an issue with the Resource.Designer class file in that it 
doesn't contain important fields or constants my custom renderer requires.

Errors are the following:

```
Resource.Layout does not contain a definition for MapInfoWindow
Resource.Id does not contain a definition for InfoWindowTitle
Resource.Id does not contain a definition for InfoWindowSubtitle
Resource.Drawable does not contain a definition for 'pin'
```

After making an attempt in adding them manually, compiler 
upon rebuilding overwrites the customized designer with
the previous version(without the necessary fields).

Has anyone experienced and solved this ?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Delete resource.designer file and rebuild your app. Again it would generate new designer file.

Comment: I've already done that, not a solution : )

Comment: Is that not wokring?

Comment: If it'd be that easy I wouldn't be here...

Comment: Closed and reopen your IDE, unload reload your project. Check you have `MapInfoWindow` layout, `InfoWindowTitle` id in your UI code. And  change build action of `pin` file to `AndroidResource`.

Comment: Try to delete `obj` and `bin` files and restart and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in the NUget logic usage.